# 3D vector indices inconsistency C++

Tags: c++, macos, stdvector

I was playing around with vectors of vectors in C++. In my case what I call a 3D-vector is shown in the following code

```
typedef std::vector<double> RandomSample;
typedef std::vector<RandomSample> TimeSample;
typedef std::vector<TimeSample> Option;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    unsigned int numberOfOptions = 3;
    unsigned int timeNodes = 7;
    unsigned int numberOfRandSamples = 10;

    Option options(3, TimeSample(7, RandomSample(numberOfRandSamples)));

    std::cout << options[0][0][0] << std::endl;
    //std::cout << options[3][6][9] << std::endl;   //SEGMENTATION FAULT
    //std::cout << options[2][7][9] << std::endl;   //SEGMENTATION FAULT
    std::cout << options[2][6][20] << std::endl;    //NO ERROR !!

    std::cout << "Hola Mundo !" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code says by itself the problem, when accessing beyond the vector bounds for the first and second indices I get the expected runtime error, but when doing the same with the third index it doesn't happen, no error, no nothing at all. I've even tried with big numbers in the third index and still everything, apparently, is working fine. What am I missing or what is going on with this code?

I'm developing on Mac OS X 10.8.4 + Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: Edited the question, only vectors of doubles.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing anything about `Option` `TimeSample` and `RandomSample`, but since you're talking about segmentation faults this is probably [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Unless you explicitly throw some error in the [] operator when the array gets accessed out of bounds, there is no guarantee in C++ that an error will occur if you go out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're expecting a runtime error when accessing a vector outside bounds with `operator[]` then it's your expectation that is wrong.

When you make that kind of mistake the C++ standard says that it's "undefined behaviour", not "runtime error".

In C++, for performance reasons, there are very few runtime error angels (i.e. checks that you're not doing something wrong at runtime) so unless you specifically request them (e.g. using `std::vector::at()` instead of `std::vector::operator[]`) or unless you implement them yourself no check will be done and whatever happens happens.

Sometimes when doing this kind of mistake you get an immediate crash, but that happens only when you're very lucky. In most common cases instead you end up corrupting data that belongs to some other object or to the runtime library and one million instructions executed later a perfectly innocent part of the program starts behaving like crazy.

Murphy says that you will only get a crash if you're giving a demonstration of your software in front of potential investors and your family. Until that point everything will seem to work perfectly even if you overwrite memory that wasn't yours.

The main philosophy of C++ is that programmers never make this kind of error ;-)

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought it should throw a runtime error. I'll check that part of the C++ standard.